# Notificaciones en el background Flutter con la aplicación cerrada

Tags: android, flutter, dart, notificaciones, background

Tengo un problema ya que estoy terminando de implementar una aplicación de alarmas, y evidentemente necesito que el propio sistema me notifique de nuevas alarmas, pero claro, sin necesidad de tener la aplicación abierta, estilo notificaciones de Whatsapp.

Se que en nativo no es dificil de implementar, pero en Flutter no estoy encontrando ningún tipo de herramienta para poder implementar esto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de dos maneras diferentes:

1. De forma local y autónoma puedes hacerlo con el paquete de notificaciones locales

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications

Lo he usado en algunas de mis aplicaciones y funciona correctamente, el único problema es que si reinicias el dispositivo estas obligado a volver a abrir la aplicación para volver a crear las alertas.

2. Usando un paquete externo como FCM o OneSignal, pero debes crearte tu propio backend para gestionar las notificaciones.